# Python - Barchart in Matplotlib - How to change X axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

simple, probably dummy question, but I can't find the answer:

How to adjust the X axis for a bar plot in Matplotlib?

my code so far:

```
_ = matplotlib.pyplot.bar(names, value, color="blue")
_.axis([-11,11,0,1])
```

returns 
--> `AttributeError: 'BarContainer' object has no attribute 'axis'`

Comment: x axis label, or the axis itself?

Comment: There are values from -100 to 100 but I only want to show values between -11 and 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xlim for this!

https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.xlim(-11, 11)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all a good practise to make things easier is to import this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

and then you can simply

```
plt.bar(names, value, color="blue")
plt.xlim([-11,11])

plt.show()
```